# Cancelling ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

Where is the right place to cancel an ongoing request of ASIHttpRequest? This is how I do my cancellation but it keep on crashing when I **transfer from one viewcontroller to another without letting the request to finish**. The cancellation fo request works fine, but when switch back to the first Viewcontroller it will crash.

```
    -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
      [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

      if(!DID_FINISH_REQUEST)
      {
        [requestNewReleases setDelegate:nil];
        [requestNewReleases cancel];
        [requestNewReleases clearDelegatesAndCancel];
      }
    }
```

Comment: How do you switch to another view ?

Comment: I'm using a TabBarController for switching ViewControllers. No problem with interrupting requests there. The problem occurs when I do a pushViewController(not finishing the request) then switch to another ViewController in my tabbar and go back to the firstViewController then pressing the back button, there it will crash. But when I let the request to finish, it will not crash. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Enable NSZombies, set a breakpoint on all exceptions, run in the debugger, see exactly why/where it's crashing.

Answer (score 3):

In the [ASIHttpRequest documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) there is an example of a request being cancelled in the dealloc method:

> Safely handling the delegate being deallocated before the request has
>   finished
>
> Requests don’t retain their delegates, so if there’s a chance your
>   delegate may be deallocated while your request is running, it is vital
>   that you clear the request’s delegate properties. In most
>   circumstances, if your delegate is going to be deallocated, you
>   probably also want to cancel request, since you no longer care about
>   the request’s status.
>
> In the example below, our controller has an ASIHTTPRequest stored in a
>   retained instance variable. We call the clearDelegatesAndCancel method
>   in it’s dealloc implementation, just before we release our reference
>   to the request:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
   [request release];
   ...
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your architecture and application needs - eg. If there are multiple http requests only some of which need to cancel?

Then solution -

```
for (ASIHTTPRequest *req in ASIHTTPRequest.sharedQueue.operations)
{
    [req cancel];
    [req setDelegate:nil];
}
```

This will cancel and remove the delegate of all in progress requests that have been assigned to the default queue.